# How to keep a randomly generated matrix constant in python?

Tags: python

this may be a stupid question but I created a matrix with randomly generated values from a deck of cards:

```
ranks = ['A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K']
suits = ['♠', '♥', '♣', '♦']

deck = []

for rank in ranks:
  for suit in suits:
    card = str(rank) + suit
    deck.append(card)

random.shuffle(deck)

matrix = [[[random.choice(deck), ''] for i in range(13)]for j in range(4)]
```

and wanted to add a method which would return 'flip' the card by returning only the value of the card:

```
def get_card(row, col):
  print(matrix[row][col][0])
```

How would I alter this code so that the values created in the matrix remain constant? Every time i call get_card(1,2), it returns a different randomly generated value.

Again, sorry if this is a stupid question and thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Are you recreating the matrix every time `get_card()` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix is constant as long as its not recreated. See example below:

```
import random

matrix = None

def create_deck():
    ranks = ['A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K']
    suits = ['♠', '♥', '♣', '♦']

    deck = []

    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            card = str(rank) + suit
            deck.append(card)

    random.shuffle(deck)

    global matrix
    matrix = [[[random.choice(deck), ''] for i in range(13)]for j in range(4)]


def get_card(row, col):
    print(matrix[row][col][0])


# First deck, get_card returns the same value
create_deck()
for _ in range(5):
    get_card(1,2)

# Create new deck, get_card returns the same value, but not the same as before
create_deck()
for _ in range(5):
    get_card(1,2)
```

Output (on my run, you will have different cards but the same pattern):

```
J♥
J♥
J♥
J♥
J♥
5♠
5♠
5♠
5♠
5♠
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. If it's not too much of a bother, I have another question. I'm trying to create another function that removes the card from the matrix:
def remove_pairs():
    matrix[row][col].pop()
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            print((matrix[i][j][1]), end = ' ')
        print('')

but I can't access the matrix (keeps returning None), but recreating it would make a new matrix. How would this work?

Comment: @AndrewOZEKI In python if you remove something from a list the list shrinks. Instead I would set it to `None` so that the space is there but not the card. `def remove_card(row, col): matrix[row][col] = [None, None]`. This way the get card function still works and prints `None`. Please mark the answer as accepted as your question has been answered

Comment: @AndrewOZEKI Can you mark the answer as accepted as you have received both answers you requested?